# Are nullable value types just wrappers around the regular value type?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

The reason I ask is that you can cast a nullable type to a regular type with the Value property. That makes me think that the regular type is just wrapped up in the nullable type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is a generic struct:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct, new()
```

This is probably more confusing if you've only seen the `T?` syntax - but that is just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar), the compiler is changing it to `Nullable<T>`.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the clarification with re: the syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - ['Nullable<T> Structure'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

> Represents an object whose underlying
>   type is a value type that can also be
>   assigned null like a reference type.

[BTW, if your curious you can use Reflector to 'look under the hood']

Answer (score 3):

According to MSDN `"Nullable types are instances of the System.Nullable<T> struct. A nullable type can represent the correct range of values for its underlying value type, plus an additional null value"`